# ¿Como añadir mi localización en Autocompletado de sitios de Google?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un autocompletado y lo que quiero es añadir la opción de que encuentre la dirección por la localización del dispositivo.

```
public void buscar() {
    try {
        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS).setCountry("ESP")
                .build();

        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                .setFilter(typeFilter)
                .build(this);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        //Error
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Has elegido: " + place.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```